# How can I use the Linesearches.jl module in Julia independent of Optim.jl?

Tags: optimization, julia, numerical-methods

I have an implementation of L-BFGS, and would like to call the line-search from LineSearches.jl to compare. However, the documentation is quite sparse and focuses only on the use of Linesearches.jl in the context of Optim.jl. I cannot find any examples of how to use Linesearches.jl indpendently.

Comment: We are currently working on making it less Optim/NLsolve-centric. Please provide more code here if you want me to show you how, open an issue at LineSearches.jl or visit the Optim.jl gitter channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an example of how to use the `LineSearches` algorithms with a [custom-made optimizer](https://julianlsolvers.github.io/LineSearches.jl/latest/examples/generated/customoptimizer.html) in the [`latest` documentation](https://julianlsolvers.github.io/LineSearches.jl/latest/).

Note that the example currently requires LineSearches `master`, but should be available in `v6.0.0` shortly.

Here's the full example, in case the links break: (**EDIT**: Updated with new example code that simplifies the process.)

### Using LineSearches without Optim/NLsolve

Say we have written a gradient descent optimization algorithm but would like to
experiment with different line search algorithms.
The algorithm is implemented as follows.

```
function gdoptimize(f, g!, fg!, x0::AbstractArray{T}, linesearch,
                    maxiter::Int = 10000,
                    g_rtol::T = sqrt(eps(T)), g_atol::T = eps(T)) where T <: Number
    x = copy(x0)
    gvec = similar(x)
    g!(gvec, x)
    fx = f(x)

    gnorm = norm(gvec)
    gtol = max(g_rtol*gnorm, g_atol)

    # Univariate line search functions
    ϕ(α) = f(x .+ α.*s)
    function dϕ(α)
        g!(gvec, x .+ α.*s)
        return vecdot(gvec, s)
    end
    function ϕdϕ(α)
        phi = fg!(gvec, x .+ α.*s)
        dphi = vecdot(gvec, s)
        return (phi, dphi)
    end

    s = similar(gvec) # Step direction

    iter = 0
    while iter < maxiter && gnorm > gtol
        iter += 1
        s .= -gvec

        dϕ_0 = dot(s, gvec)
        α, fx = linesearch(ϕ, dϕ, ϕdϕ, 1.0, fx, dϕ_0)

        @. x = x + α*s
        g!(gvec, x)
        gnorm = norm(gvec)
    end

    return (fx, x, iter)
end
```

Note that there are many optimization and line search algorithms that allow
the user to evaluate both the objective and the gradient at the same time, for
computational efficiency reasons.
We have included this functionality in the algorithm as the input function `fg!`,
and even if the Gradient Descent algorithm does not use it explicitly, many of the LineSearches algorithms do.

The Gradient Descent `gdoptimize` method selects a descent direction and calls
the line search algorithm  `linesearch` which returns the step length `α` and the
objective value `fx = f(x + α*s)`.

The functions ϕ and dϕ represent a univariate objective
and its derivative, which is used by the line search algorithms.
To utilize the `fg!` function call in the optimizer, some of the line searches
require a function ϕdϕ which returns the univariate objective and the
derivative at the same time.

### Optimizing Rosenbrock

Here is an example to show how we can combine `gdoptimize` and `LineSearches`
to minimize the Rosenbrock function, which is defined by

```
f(x) = (1.0 - x[1])^2 + 100.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2)^2

function g!(gvec, x)
    gvec[1] = -2.0 * (1.0 - x[1]) - 400.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2) * x[1]
    gvec[2] = 200.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2)
    gvec
end

function fg!(gvec, x)
    g!(gvec, x)
    f(x)
end
```

We can now use `gdoptimize` with `BackTracking` to optimize the Rosenbrock function
from a given initial condition `x0`.

```
x0 = [-1., 1.0]

using LineSearches
ls = BackTracking(order=3)
fx_bt3, x_bt3, iter_bt3 = gdoptimize(f, g!, fg!, x0, ls)
```

Interestingly, the `StrongWolfe` line search converges in one iteration, whilst
all the other algorithms take thousands of iterations.
This is just luck due to the particular choice of initial condition

```
ls = StrongWolfe()
fx_sw, x_sw, iter_sw = gdoptimize(f, g!, fg!, x0, ls)
```